# placing xmlns:xsi into my schema using java

Tags: java, xml

I have the following bit of code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\", xmlns=\"http://www.europe.xsd","EMOTable1");//create the rootelement
document.appendChild(rootElement);//append the root element to the doc
```

The issue is when i run the code i dont get the following created xmlns:xsi after EMOtable1 like:

```
<EMOTable1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.europe.xsd">
```

I dont exactly know what the xmlns:xsi means, and then further to this how do i get this inserted?

I am using javax library

This is what is currently written

```
<EMOTABLE1 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot;xmlns=&quot;http://www.europe.xsd">
```

@wero

Comment: Have you tried setting the DocumentBuilderFactory to be namespace-aware? (By default it is not.) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware%28boolean%29

Comment: @ reowil  that hasnt helped its just turned all my backslashes into &quot

Comment: I don't think I understand what happened; how is the EMOTable1 element written? Still without the xmlns-parts? (The value of "xmlns:xsi" is a reference to a schema instance, and the value of just "xmlns" is used for the default namespace. Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_schema.asp, under the heading "Referencing a Schema in an XML Document".)

Comment: @reowil i have added to my question what i currently get written to notepad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first create the namespaced element:

```
Element rootElement = doc.createElementNS("http://www.europe.xsd", "EMOTable1");
```

and then add the second namespace declaration

```
rootElement.setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

Comment: output isnt right still its backwards and the xmlns:xsi still doesnt appear after EMOTable1 - i have shown what i get output to my question

Comment: @MrAssistance order of attributes in a XML element is not significant and you should not rely on a specific order

Comment: <EMOTable1 xmlns="http://www.europe.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> but here doesnt the xmllns:xsi refer to the latter URL rather than the former?

Comment: @MrAssistance no they are completely unrelated.

Comment: @ wero i would feel better if i can get this in the right order is there not a way? I currently have the order back to front but the URL refers to the correct xmlns:xsi and xmlns respectively

Comment: I don't think it would alter anything (actually, I think it's only logical that the namespace is declared before it's used so I personally would not want to change their order), but would it not be possible (and perhaps even more correct) to use `rootElement.setAttributeNS("http://www.europe.xsd", "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")` instead of `setAttribute`? (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#setAttributeNS(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))